# sql get max of multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL server 2008 R2, how do you get the MAX result if you have two rows that have the same value?  I have a table that I use to store the data about the number of times a client is seen at a location.

```
create table #templocation
(
    ClientID        Int,
    Location        Varchar(100),
    LocationCount           Int,
    MaxCount        Int
)
```

I only fill the first three columns with an insert statement then I get the max for each client like this:

```
update t
set t.MaxCount = t2.locationcount 
from #templocation t
join (select tl.ClientID, MAX(tl.LocationCount) as 'locationcount'
    from #templocation tl
    group by tl.ClientID) t2
on t2.ClientID = t.ClientID         

update t
set t.PrimaryLocation = tl.Location 
from #temp t
join  #templocation tl
on t.ClientId = tl.ClientID 
where tl.LocationCount = tl.MaxCount
```

I then join this to the main table to get the final results.  My problem is if a client is has two or more max counts.  Then it wants to display all of the max locations like this:

```
ClientId Location LocationCount
12502    Main St. 4
12502    Lake Ave 4
12502    Tracy Rd 2
```

The results I get are:

```
ClientId ClientName Location
12502    John Smith Main St.
12502    John Smith Lake Ave
```

I only want the first or top one displayed though preferably by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do things like this through a couple of CTEs.  One will give us the `max(locationcount)` for each client, and one just adds a `row_number()`  for every clientid so we can pick the "first" location".

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53add5/1)

It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

```
;with maxrows as
(select
ClientID as ClientID,
max(LocationCount) as MaxValue
--row_number() OVER (partition by ClientID order by ClientID)
from
table1
group by ClientID)
,
rowcounts as
(
select
t1.ClientID,
t1.Location,
row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ClientID order by t1.Location) as RowNum
from
table1 t1
  )


select
t2.ClientID,
t2.Location
from
maxrows t1
inner join rowcounts t2
  on t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID
  and t2.rownum = 1
```

Comment: I sort of had the same idea without using CTEs (still trying to get a handle on CTEs): update t set t.MaxCount = t.New_MaxCount 
from (select t2.MaxCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by t2.ClientID Order by t2.ClientId, t2.LocationCount desc, t2.Location) as 'New_MaxCount'
  from #templocation t2) t

Comment: Although this is a bit of an over-simplification, I view a CTE as pretty much the same things as a derived table.  Only real difference I can think of is a CTE can be self-referencing (which tends to make my head hurt).

Answer (score 0):

From how I understood the issue, you could use `MAX() OVER ()` to achieve what you want like this:

```
WITH maxvalues AS (
  SELECT
    ClientId,
    Location,
    LocationCount,
    MaxCount = MAX(LocationCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  ClientId,
  Location
FROM maxvalues
WHERE LocationCount = MaxCount
;
```

Join `maxvalues` to whatever table holds the client names to include those into the output too.

Learn more about the OVER clause in this manual:

- [OVER clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)